# libvirtError: operation failed: could not query memory balloon allocation

Tags: debian-squeeze, libvirt, kvm-virtualization

Trying to install kvm vm with virt-manager  and I've got this error. This machine has 16gb of memory and I entered 4096MB. What's the problem in here?

```
    Unable to complete install '<class 'libvirt.libvirtError'> operation failed: could not query memory balloon allocation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/create.py", line 1571, in do_install
    vm.startup()
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/domain.py", line 1297, in startup
    self._update_status()
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/domain.py", line 1902, in _update_status
    info = self.get_info()
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/domain.py", line 1212, in get_info
    return self._backend.info()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 766, in info
    if ret is None: raise libvirtError ('virDomainGetInfo() failed', dom=self)
libvirtError: operation failed: could not query memory balloon allocation
'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

you can maximum setup 4095 rams with qemu

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support more RAM, you should install package `kvm` too, It related to your debian's version:
for install kvm on debian 7 (wheezy), you should run this command:

```
# apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin virtinst
```

BUT for install kvm on debian 6 (sqeeze), you should run this command:

```
# apt-get install kvm qemu-kvm libvirt-bin virtinst
```